# Getting this error Status : Failure -Test failed: IO Error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection

Tags: oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am new to Oracle, installed oracle SQL developer but each time I try to connect, I get the error:

> Status: Failure -Test failed: IO Error: The Network Adapter could not
> establish the connection

and the oracleTNSlistener service turns off on its own. Each time I start the service, it turns off immediately on its own.

Comment: does the database service run successfully? what happens if you try to start the listener manually, open a cmd prompt, run, lsnrctl start

Comment: ok so when i try starting the listener from services, it would start then go off on its own. tried manually through cmd prompt and this is the error;TNS-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error
 TNS-00530: Protocol adapter error